# Vuforia Engine Unity: Successful test in editor, but image tracking fails on iOS (iOS 17) device – What might be causing this issue?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, unity-editor

I'm currently working with the Vuforia Engine in Unity and encountered a puzzling problem. I followed the basic getting started guide for testing purposes, and everything appears to work seamlessly within the Unity editor. The build process is successful, and the app installs on my iPhone (iOS 17) without any issues.

However, upon launching the app on my iPhone, I'm faced with a peculiar problem. The camera activates, but the image tracking functionality fails to work. Despite following the standard procedures, the app doesn't seem to recognize and track the target image.

Additional Details:
Vuforia Engine version: 10.20
iOS device: iPhone 15 pro max | iPhone 14 | running iOS 17
Questions:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Vuforia image tracking on iOS devices?
Are there any specific considerations or settings for iOS builds that might impact image tracking?
Could there be compatibility issues between Vuforia and iOS 17?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Steps Taken:

Followed the Vuforia Engine getting started guide.
Successfully tested the app within the Unity editor.
Completed a successful build and installed the app on an iPhone running iOS 17.
Upon launch, only the camera is visible, and image tracking does not occur.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using (note that Vuforia recommends 2022.3 https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/supported-versions ). Have you tried to deploy one the core samples provided here https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-core-samples-99026 ? Does the sample work?

Comment: @emay 
I have tried using Unity version 2022.3.17f1 Silicon, both on macOS and Windows, and encountered the same issue where image tracking fails on an iOS device.

In an attempt to resolve the problem, I followed your advice and tried the recommended Unity version. However, during the Xcode build stage, I encountered a new issue: "Library 'GameAssembly' not found."

I have double-checked my setup and followed the recommended procedures, but this error persists. I'm seeking further assistance to understand the cause of this new issue and any potential solutions.

Comment: 2022.3.17f1 should work, it is same major version. My recommendation is to start from the Core Sample and check if you have the same tracking problem on your device. If that one works then you can try to replace the target dataset in the Core Sample with your target. If your target also works then you should look at setup differences between your app and the CoreSample